# Azure SignalR and Azure Web Application with multiple instances

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-signalr

We are developing ASP.Net core that is hosted as Azure Web Application.

We also use Azure SignalR service

Everything works great as long as we have single instance of the Web App, but once we scale it out we have the following problem:

1. From the Controller's action we resolve IHubContext and we send message to Hub's client. Everything works great so far
2. Hub's client accepts response and sends it TheHub endpoint.

The problem here is that response could be sent to another instance of Web App. So we send request from instance #1 but response is sent to instance #2 with 50% chance and instance #1 never receives response

Any ideas of how we could make it work so instance that emitted request actually received response?

Comment: Like the web app itself, SignalR was also to be stateless.  The best bet is to configure your session provider like Radis store what it needs to, and not worry about which web server your SignalR client connects to.

Comment: Your web app itself can be a SignalR client that talks to the hub, so that your hub has 1) browser clients and 2) web app client(s) and work merely as a proxy. Then when your web app expands to multiple hosts, your hub still knows which web app client it should forward the message to.

Answer (score 1):

SignalR has support for scaleout scenarios out of the box, it's called backplanes. The idea is that with help of one of backplane components, it will spread out SignalR events accross all instances. For Asp.Net framework, use one of these packages

- `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus3`
- `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.ServiceBus`
- `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.StackExchangeRedis`
- `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer`

For ASP.Net Core only Redis is ported with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.StackExchangeRedis` package, but there are some provided by community, see https://github.com/thomaslevesque/AspNetCore.SignalR.AzureServiceBus

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSignalR()
                    .AddAzureSignalR(options =>
                    {
                        options.ApplicationName = "app1";
                    }
                );
        }
```

You could specify an ApplicationName in the server SDK for different server groups.

It will help your server generate access tokens like ......?hub=app1_<your_hub> during negotiation which can help our ASRS instances differentiate connections coming from different server groups

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn't find reliable solution that wouldn't require a bit clumsy workarounds

But there are 2 solutions I could offer for this scenario

1. @LexLi suggested a good approach to solve this problem. So you basically can make your web app a SignalR client as well and make it a member of a group. This way every instance of web app is also a client and then instance that receives response for Hub's client can pass this response to group of web app instances
2. You could leverage Azure Service Bus topics. So once started instance will start subscribe to listen a topic. And then once any instance receives a response from Hub's client it would place response into Service Bus Topic and then every instance will receive this response from the topic

I was hoping that there could be a better solution for such problem